# Copying and adding JSON schema as array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to add a copy of a key and its content to the JSON file by using php.

```
$content = file_get_contents($_POST["content"]);
$decode = json_decode($content,true);
$version = $_POST["version"];
array_unshift($decode['versions'],$version );
$encode = json_encode($decode,true);
```

Let's say we want to add the version 1.2.2. This adds:

```
...["versions"]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(5) "1.2.2" ["1.2.1"]=> array(4) { ["project"]=> string(21)...
```

instead of creating a 1.2.2 key and its sub arrays.

Also tried:

```
array_unshift($decode['versions'][$version],$version );
```

without results either

Comment: Can you show us an example of what is inside `$version` and `$decode` ?

Comment: $version has the version that I am trying to add. 1.2.2 in the example. $decode contains the decoded version of the json file by using the PHP function json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestand correctly, you can directly put the version inside your content like this :

```
$content = file_get_contents($_POST['content']);
$decode = json_decode($content, true);

$version = $_POST['version'];
$decode['version'] = $version;

$encode = json_encode($decode, true);
```